# Can one create generic macro that works on multiple worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel, events, worksheet

I have created a simple worksheet macro that sends the contents of a cell to an external program when the cell is double clicked. At first, I had all of the code in the sheet module, and had to copy it to each sheet on which I wanted the functionality. Now, I managed to reduce the code in the sheet module to a call to a subroutine in a standard module and it works, but I stil have to copy the code to each sheet on which I need the functionality. Is there a way to enter the code in only one place (a standard module, workbook module or class module) and have it function on any sheet in the workbook without code behind the sheet? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The `ThisWorkbook` code module has a `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` event handler which you can use instead of capturing the event separately on each sheet.

Comment: +1. If you want the double-click to fire on every sheet in the workbook, use this. You can also use this if you don't by checking for sheets on an exclusion list.

Comment: Yes `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` is the right place to run the macro from.

Answer (score 2):

You need an event handler on the sheet to take care of the double-click. Put this in the code behind each sheet you want to run the double-click code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sWorksheet As String
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim sCell As String

    sWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    sValue = Target.Text
    sCell = Target.Address
    Call DoubleClicked(sWorksheet, sValue, sCell)
End Sub
```

Put your main routine in a module, and not on the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoubleClicked(SheetName As String, CellText As String, CellAddress As String)
    ' your code goes here
    MsgBox "You double-clicked cell " & CellAddress & " on sheet " _
    & SheetName & ". The text in that cell is: " & CellText
End Sub
```

You don't want the logic repeated on each sheet. If you make a change, you have to change it for every single sheet. By simply calling the main routine from each sheet, you only have to write and maintain it once.